# Can bonsai be made from a walnut seedling?

Tags: trees, bonsai

I managed to sprout a nut and now I have a walnut. Can I make a bonsai?[image]

Comment: Yes, if you do the right things, you will get a nice bonsai after 10 or 20 years. But walnut is not an easy tree to bonsai, because it "bleeds" if it is pruned when it is not dormant. Also, it will never grow small leaves, so a bonsai less than about a meter tall will look very unnatural.

Comment: Mulțumesc mult!

Comment: Yes, but it should be planted with only green stem above the soil. But keep it as it is for now. Once the nut comes loose, you can replant it - into a much smaller pot if you want to keep it small. Cute, isn't it?

Comment: There is a lot not know about walnut, perhaps for lack of North American folks trying. You may be able to figure out things like how to encourage leaves to be of reduced size and all that which would be an awesome contribution to the art.

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no. Indeed you can make a short tapering trunk as with any deciduous species, but the leaves remain just about as big as one in an orchard. So it isn't very pleasing in leaf.

However, most deciduous bonsai are prized for their branch structure which is seen in winter. In my experience, it is frustratingly difficult to make a nice branch structure because of the large compound leaves.

I had a lot of fun with sprouts from seeds that were apparently planted by squirrels in my yard. I grew them in a larger pot until the seedling didn't need the nut, then planted them in very small (one or two inch diameter) pots. It found it quite amusing to have two or three inch long trunks with 6 inch compound leaves hanging off them! They are indeed a lot of fun for a while. Other species like horse chestnut and maples miniaturize themselves when kept small and are much more rewarding as legitimate bonsai.

Perhaps Google translate will help.

Comment: Vă mulțumesc tuturor pentru răspunsuri!

Comment: Cu plăcere. A se distra. Bucurați-vă. (Google translate)

Comment: I put a picture of my walnut.